# Get notified when Type gets registered in UnityContainer

Tags: c#, .net, unity-container, prism

I'm in a PRISM + Unity Environment. Is it possible to get notified when a Type gets registered via

```
UnityContainer.RegisterType<IMyType,MyType>();
```

Like is there an Event or something that gets raised when this Method is called somewhere else?

Comment: why do you need this? Normally, type registrations should be finished at startup time before actually running the app.

Comment: My goal is to add some components via the regionmanager to a region as soon as a specific type is registered. The Module where these types get registered shouldn't know anything about this

Answer (score 1):

You can write a custom extension to the unity container. The base class for that is `UnityContainerExtension`. In that you have access to the events you are looking for.

```
public class NotificationUnityExtension : UnityContainerExtension
{
    protected override void Initialize()
    {
        Context.Registering += (sender, args) =>
        {
            // Called when type is registered
            Console.WriteLine($"Registering type {args.TypeTo.Name}");
        };
        Context.RegisteringInstance += (sender, args) =>
        {
            // Called when instance is registered
            Console.WriteLine($"Registering instance of type {args.Instance.GetType().Name}");
        };
    }
}
```

It's used like that:

```
var container = new UnityContainer();
container.AddExtension(new NotificationUnityExtension());
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if there is any event like this (I may be wrong) but how about a simple solution like this?

```
UnityContainer.RegisterType<IMyType,MyType>();
        if(UnityContainer.IsRegistered<IMyType>())
        {
           /* Do your stuff i.e. add some components via
              the regionmanager to a region as soon as a specific type
              is registered */
        }
```

Comment: That wouldn't help because I would have to check frequently

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure If that would be a solution for you. I suppose you checked UnityContainer API already if such event exists. Couldn't you wrap component registration with your own method and raise an event there?

Comment: I thought of this solution already but I wanted to ask for an alternative before doing this. That's the reason for this question :). Didn't found anything in my own search.